# Bash using netcat, send one command's output to file

Tags: bash, expect, netcat

I need to know how to grab output and store it in a variable. I don't want to send all the output to the file, just one of the commands output I am sending.. Basically

```
AUTH
AUTH
LIST  <---needs to go to file
```

I tried..
`read $response` but it isn't working.

Comment: Out of many output which one in specific you want to store. Only LIST for one time purpose or you want a script of it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to eliminate $:

```
read response
```

Answer (score 0):

`nc` isn't `expect`, so you have no control over which parts of the remote host's output are captured.  You can redirect the entire output to a file (and process the file later with `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, or whatever to extract only what you need) or pipe it directly into `awk` (or whatever) before writing to a file or storing it in a shell variable (with `$()` command substitution).

However, you'd almost certainly be better off writing your script in `perl` (and use either the `Expect.pm` module or `Net::Telnet`, or `Net::IMAP`) or in `python` using `pexpect` (or `python`'s `imaplib2` library), or in some other language with an `expect`-like library or IMAP client library.

That would allow you to connect to the relevant port (IMAP, by the look of it) on the remote host, issue whatever commands you need, wait for responses, and do whatever you need with the response (including saving some of the responses to a file)

I've added the `/expect` tag to your question - click on it to get a list of `expect`-related questions and answers on this site.